# Use npm modules in spring boot application

Tags: node.js, spring-boot, bootstrap-4, node-modules

How can I install third-party plugins as node_modules and access them inside a spring boot web application?

Answer (score -1):

1. Generate a new Spring Boot project Step
2. Split the project into separate modules
3. Add the Angular2 application to the project
4. Configure Maven to build the Angular2 application
5. Let Spring Boot serve the Angular2 application
6. Fire it up!
7. Using the angular-cli development server with your Spring Boot backend

Click [here](https://blog.jdriven.com/2016/12/angular2-spring-boot-getting-started/) to see full description.

Comment: its fine but if you explained in detail manner then it will be better.

Comment: @see this link will be heplful to you http://justincalleja.com/2016/04/17/serving-a-webpack-bundle-in-spring-boot/

Comment: @Rajan Desai, mine is not an angular application. I just need to use some jquery plugins as npm packages.